# How to add manufacturer and supplier part numbers to components in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, bom

I recently switched to Eagle for my board designs. Because most components I use are not in the predefined libraries, I've made a "Managed Library" myself. When making the BOM list (using a predefined ULP from Eagle), I really miss the manufacturer and supplier part numbers (eg. Farnell or DigiKey numbers). It would be nice if I can add them to my "Managed Library" in such a way that the BOM ULP from Eagle outputs them accordingly in the BOM list.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I see that Eagle allows attributes added to a symbol and allows them to be selectively displayed.  Right click on a symbol in the schematic editor to see the options.

Answer (score 4):

I added attributes to all my components like so:
[image: screenshots of eaglecad library and ulp dialog]

Then I use the bom_w_attr_v2.ulp (available on the eaglecad website) to generate a BOM that contains all the part numbers.